# The space $\Omega^1(X)$ of hyperelliptic curve $X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

This is a problem I encountered when reading Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces by Rick Miranda:

Show that if $X$ is a hyperelliptic curve with genus $g$ defined by $y^2=h(x)$, then the space $\Omega^1(X)=\{p(x)\frac{dx}{y}|\deg(p)\leq g-1\}$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: any thoughts? ${}$

Comment: You need to prove these are all actually (linearly independent) holomorphic differentials. The definition of genus $g$ is $\dim H^0(X,\Omega^1) = g$.